# How to escape variable in js.erb on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I want to alert my instance variable to inspect my variable by

```
alert('<%= j @user');
```

but I got error about FIXNUM

but the following code works.

```
$('#user_div').html('<%= j render(:partial=> 'found_user', 
    locals: { user: @user }, :formats => :html) %>');
```

Thanks :P

Comment: What's the exact error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the missing `%>`

```
alert('<%= j @user %>');
```